# Class from XSD folders/schemas

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xsd

I've done before when i have XSD schema and by running simple script it would created me a .NET class

```
xsd.exe File-v1-0.xsd /classes /language:vb Dependcy-v1-0.xsd Dependency2-v2-1.xsd /out:c:\completed
```

That is nice one. But now i have a problem when my xsd schema looks like this

[image]

Folder commom has a lot more xmls

[image]

So the question is. How can i create the vb.net class from this bulk of files.

Do i really need to go and write down one by one or is there easier way ?

Edit: Even when i list all files in one command line i get the error :

> Schema validation warning: The complexType
>   'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2:AccountingDocumentLabelType'
>   has already been declared. Line 102, position 4.

Comment: The root XSD should reference the children (including path) so when you use the XSD tool it should automatically find the children and create all the classes.

Comment: @jdweng `Error: Error generating classes for schema 'xsd\OutGoingInvoicesData'.
  - The element 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2:Invoice' is missing.`

Comment: The root XSD needs to be edited.  Often standard schema have customized sections and you need to modify the custom sections as required.  Here the location of the child scemas need modifications.